# TeXStudio - Cross-reference in case of multiple files

Tags: cross-referencing, texstudio, multiple-files

I have a master document and for each chapter a separate file like:

main.tex

```
% preamble etc.

\input{chapter1}
\input{chapter2}
\input{chapter3}
% and so on
```

chapter1.tex

```
% Some figure with a label, tex code not shown, just the label
\label{fig:chicken}
% Some figure with a label, tex code not shown, just the label
\label{fig:monkey}

This two-legs animal is a chicken as shown in \cref{fig:chicken} % OK! Works within the same chapter! fig. 1
```

chapter2.tex

```
Here I like to refer to \ref{fig:monkey} % results in ??
```

Referring to a label in another chapter results in a double question mark (I did compile multiple times). LyX has the option to set a master document for each "included" tex-file. Document > Settings > Select default master document.

How can I do this in TeXstudio? I've already set main.tex as the master document but can't find a way to refer from its childs back to the master document like in LyX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to add the \label{} after or inside \caption{}

main.tex

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[justification=RaggedRight, singlelinecheck=false]{caption} 

\begin{document}

 \input{chapter1}
 \input{chapter2}

\end{document}
```

chapter1.tex

```
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\begin{figure}[h!]
 \caption{ Test}
  \label{fig:chicken}
  \includegraphics{chicken}
 \end{figure}
```

chapter2.tex

```
\chapter{Chapter 2}

Here I like to refer to \cref{fig:chicken}
```

Output

```
Here I like to refer to fig. 1.1
```

Comment: I discovered that the package cleveref should be included after hyperref and if used, amsmath, thanks to your example SLx64. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes you have to include the hyperref package bevor cleveref if you want to use it. If it works for you, please accept my answer.

Comment: I'd love too, needs reputation of 15 for that, it seems.

Comment: There is a check mark under the two arrows. :)

Comment: Oh, thanks! SLx64. Have a nice day.

Comment: Would it be possible to make it say "figure" instead of "fig."? I am used to using the \figref command which generally works well. I have lately been experiencing some trouble with this command and am looking for a more elegant way of cross referencing figures, tables, etc. Thanks in advance.